# Chemical potential related with quantum and classical limit in ideal gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-statistics

For ideal gas we have chemical potential

$\mu = \tau \ln \left(\frac{n}{n_Q}\right) $
where $n = N/V$ number density and 
$n_Q = \left(\frac{M\tau}{2\pi \hbar^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} $
Note we call classical limit when $n<<n_Q$,
So for this classical limit, the chemical potential of an ideal gas is always negative.

What is the physical interpretation of above statement? 
What is the meaning of negative chemical potential?

---

@rmhleo, you can find above things in Kitel;s textbook, or you can find similar things in here http://young.physics.ucsc.edu/112/ideal.pdf.

Comment: Can you give a reference to your sources? Where can I refer to in order to check and understand your equations?